# Not able to see copyField in Solr query results

Tags: solr

**Changes in `managed-scehma`**

```
<field name="aName" type="strings"/>
<field name="bName" type="strings"/>
<field name="cName" type="strings"/>
<field name="dName" type="strings"/>

<field name="autocomplete" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

<copyField source="aName" dest="autocomplete"/>
<copyField source="bName" dest="autocomplete"/> 
<copyField source="cName" dest="autocomplete"/> 
<copyField source="dName" dest="autocomplete"/> 

<fieldType name="strings" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

While querying in Solr UI, I am not seeing `autocomplete` field after restarting solr. What am I missing?

Comment: you have reindexed right?

Comment: @Persimmonium I thought it will be done on restarting. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform reindex operation in order to see changes.

> The term "reindex" is not a special thing you can do with Solr. It
>   literally means "index again." You just have to restart Solr (or
>   reload your core), possibly delete the existing index, and then repeat
>   whatever actions you took to build your index in the first place.

Which ways you have:

- Perform a normal indexing from your datasource (DB, files, REST service) as you did before. Do not forget to clean up the core/collection before.
- In case you do not have access to the first way, you could try to reindex Solr from Solr itself.

> Using Solr as a data source to build a new index is only possible if
>   your index meets the explicit requirements (`<updateLog/>` must be
>   configured in your `solrconfig.xml` in order for atomic document
>   updates to be used). If some of your
>   fields don't meet this criteria, you won't be able to recover that
>   data. It's simply not possible.

For more information take a look at the [wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToReindex#Using_Solr_as_a_Data_Source)